# I want to get duration from video links

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, youtube

I want to get duration from video links . it could be a youtube video as well as another video link. But youtube videos are playing in iframes and another are working in video tag. but im only able to fetch duration from video tag. How could get video duration from both iframe and video.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()" type="button">Get video length</button><br>

<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls>
    <source src="https://dev.theappkit.co.uk/stylco/public/images/hair_styles/0_427_serena_grant_1619797376.mp4"
        type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

<script>
    var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

    function myFunction() {
        alert(vid.duration);
    } 
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);
    function myHandler(e) {
        alert("ended");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: what is the issue it is working fine video length shows alert 11.5 and after completed video alert appears with ended text

Comment: The content of the YT iframe embed gets loaded from a different domain, so you have no JavaScript access to it from your end. They provide an IFrame Player API - but I don't think you can get the video length from that. So you would need to get the video ID, and then request this data via the actual YT API.